# Testing progressive web apps on android on virtual host over https

Tags: progressive-web-apps

I am trying to test progressive web app on Android. Its working fine on my local machine on virtual host over https. I am not able to test it on my mobile. Is there a way I can run my virtual host over https on Android mobile (locally).

I have tried enabling usb debugging as well. I can detect my mobile on chrome browser on windows but I can't browse the url of the site, it gives site can't be reached.